# HTTP ERROR: 500 by developing web application using Eclipse

Tags: java

I created a web application and all seems to run ok, but when I launch the Web browser using http://localhost:8888/  , it returns a HTTP ERROR: 500.
However, I changed the java path from 1.8 to 1.7 but still I have the problem

Problem accessing /. Reason:

```
Unable to compile class for JSP:
```

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:

Caused by:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)

Comment: This is a viable question, post some code, some errors ,etc. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what's the logs under eclipse after you have the error ?

Comment: Yeah check your server's logs, HTTP 500 denotes a server error so you should find some error logs in the server console on Eclipse. If you don't see anything in the logs, make sure your server actually listens on the 8888 port ; it might be another software receiving your request and replying with HTTP 500

Comment: @WilomGfx Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:

Caused by:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: @L.Carbonne you can now see the error.

Comment: what's the version of tomcat ?

Comment: @L.Carbonne what do you mean by tomcat? I'm using Eclipse 4.6

Comment: a JavaEE web application need a web container (or servlet container) to work, tomcat is one of most used

Comment: @L.Carbonne I don't know how to find the version of tomcat

Comment: right click on your project -> properties -> server

But you have many thing to configure when creating a JavaEE web app,
I suggest you to find and follow a good tutorial on the web

Comment: @L.Carbonne it says the project cannot be used with servers. Actually I'm following a tutorial given by instructor :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a conflict between different version of java compiler

You should verify you are using corresponding :

- JRE version
- Java build path with librairies of the servlet container you use
- Java Compiler
- Servlet container